# how to avoid Links inside iframe with "#" making parent view go to top

Tags: html, css, iframe, scroll, parent

I have a page with some content and an iframe.

Inside the iframe some links don't have hash at the end, but one does "#someanchor". When the user clicks the link with the #, the parent view scrolls to top.

I tried adding

```
     .....
     <a name="someanchor"> <iframe stuff...> </a>
```

but it still scrolls to top.

How can I avoid this behavior? Thanks,

Comment: Try `return false` using jquery

Comment: I am not sure to understand, you mean: add an on click event which manipulates window.location inside the iframe, that function should also return false? thanks, T.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$("iframe.myiframe",document).on("click","a",function(){
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I've tried to add it to the page inside the iframe and also to the page containing it but at no avail.

Comment: did you add class `myiframe` to your iframe? if not you have to set the same class or just remove the class if you want it on all iframes

Comment: I've added it to the page containing the iframe, say there's only one iframe so $("iframe", document).on("click","a",function(){console.log("click"); return false;}); when I click on a link inside the iframe, "click" is not logged! So something is not selected correctly I guess. Thanks for the patience, T.

Comment: can you please provide a fiddle? and try to add `pointer-events:none!important;` to anchors in iframe